# No data in GET response

Tags: javascript, get, axios, odata

Trying to make a GET Request to SAP OData. The connections works -> response status is 200 but console.log(res) doesnt give me any json objects, i just get some information about the request, response url and so on.

```
 axios.get(url,{
    withCredentials: true,
    params: {
      json:true
    },
    auth: {
      username: 'blablablablabla',
      password: 'blub123blub123blub123'
    }
  })
.then(res => {
    console.log(res.status);
    console.log("success!");
    console.log(res);
})

.catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message);
    console.log(err.response.status);

})
```

Comment: `res` contains the whole response object not just your json. How else could you call `res.status`. Try `res.response` for the json.

Comment: try to console.log the `res.data`, that's where the "json" should be if the url really returns it

Comment: Have you used the DevTools of your browser to look at the actual response to see if it contains your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data));
```

thanks to ziga1337 for the hint

Comment: Why do your request a JSON to stringify it?

Comment: Without it just showed me [Object] in my console, I was trying to see the actual data